# A book where the main character either dreams or gets teleported to another world by touching a boiler; their brain ages but their body does not

Tags: story-identification, books, teleportation

I read a book 5-6 years ago where the protagonist is able to be teleported to another world where his brain ages but his body doesn't, or he is able to dream like this. He is able to keep the knowledge he gained in the other world. Years pass in the other place. This happens when he touches a heater or boiler. the setting was during modern times. From what I remember, the place he was teleported to was an island that was full of either trees or bamboo. He also comes back to his world. Time goes slower in the other world ( ex: years in the other world would be hours in the real world). I’m pretty sure he is able to do this multiple times, and he does it while others sleep.

I’m pretty sure the cover had a picture of a river.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What year was "a long time ago?"  Was is a paperback or a hardcover?  Is his home like modern times?  What is the other world like?

Comment: Hi and welcome! When you can, please take the [tour] and look at the [help] when you can? You'll learn about voting and accepting answers there. Also while you can, have a look at [story identification page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and see if you can [edit] in some of the information that page asks for, it would be great!

Comment: @DavidW Hi, I read this book around 5-6 years ago. It was a paperback, and his home was during modern times. I do not know if I remember correctly, but there was this place that was like an island full of trees or bamboo. I’m sorry if that doesn’t help. :)

Comment: Possibility One: Was he a US war veteran in California in the 1940's?  Possibility Two: Did he travel to a whole sequence of worlds, including one where a child of his who had died in infancy was alive and grown up?

Comment: Does he return to the same time he left? If not, does he disappear from the original world while in other one, or does he just remain there, unaging? And by the "brain aging", do you mean that he's approaching senility earlier?